# Explode string into array with no empty elements?

Tags: php, arrays, string, filtering, explode

PHP's explode function returns an array of strings split on some provided substring. It will return empty strings when there are leading, trailing, or consecutive delimiters, like this:

```
var_dump(explode('/', '1/2//3/'));
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
  [3]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Is there some different function or option or anything that would return everything *except* the empty strings?

```
var_dump(different_explode('/', '1/2//3/'));
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Try [preg_split](http://php.net/preg_split).

`$exploded = preg_split('@/@', '1/2//3/', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Comment: I think this is the most correct because it maintains the correct array indexes.

Comment: @Ryono: what do you mean by that, exactly?

Comment: preg_split will return an array with sequential array indexes, (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3). Some of the other suggestions using array_filter will return non-sequential array indexes because some elements are filtered out and you're left with array indexes like 0,1,3,7.

Comment: @RafikBari The first character of a regex pattern is its delimiter. See http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php. `/` is typically used, but I used `@` here as `/` was in our string.

Comment: If the only reason is to get an array with non empty entries, you should use array_filter(explode()) option which is faster than preg_split.

Comment: @ceejay it would be better if the explanation of your snippet existed in the answer body instead of in the comments under the answer.

Comment: @simsek calling `array_filter()` will also destroy `0` elements in the output -- a side effect that this answer doesn't suffer.

Comment: @mickmackusa You have enough rep to propose an edit, if you desire.

Comment: I wouldn't want to put words in your mouth.  Your answer deserves your own personal explanation.

Comment: @mickmackusa Feel free. That's why SO has an edit button.

Comment: You are the one harvesting unicorn points from this code + link answer.  Surely you can spare the time to role model better posting behaviors.

Comment: I am comfortable with the state of the thirteen year old answer as it stands.

Comment: I would make the pattern `@/+@` so that potentially longer matches are made, fewer replacements are needed, and the NO_EMPTY flag has less mopping up to do.

Comment: @ceejayoz The third argument to `preg_split()` should be `-1` instead of `NULL`, as it accepts an integer. Especially important as we are moving towards typed variables in PHP 8 and higher.

Answer (score 33):

array_filter will remove the blank fields, here is an example without the filter:

```
print_r(explode('/', '1/2//3/'))
```

prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] =>
    [3] => 3
    [4] =>
)
```

With the filter:

```
php> print_r(array_filter(explode('/', '1/2//3/')))
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [3] => 3
)
```

You'll get all values that resolve to "false" filtered out.

see  http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: This will remove '0', too, as it is false in a boolean context. So it might not be what you want!

Comment: For clarity, "No" was just an answer to "Is there some different function or option or anything" -- I could have been clearer by saying "No, there's nothing built in."

Comment: This was just what I needed. I had to make sure a constant array always had four string values, which must be obtained from an explode. However, if the explode fails, I needed to provide a fallback value at [0]. I've achieved it this way: `array_filter(explode(',',($string, 4))) + ['default_value','','','']`. That way, a failed explode will contain no values, and the result will entirely be the second array. It's certainly unorthodox, but it's clean solution for a constant like this.

Answer (score 7):

Just for variety:

```
array_diff(explode('/', '1/2//3/'), array(''))
```

This also works, but does mess up the array indexes unlike preg_split. Some people might like it better than having to declare a callback function to use array_filter.

Comment: There's no need for a callback function when you use array_filter if you're filtering just falsy values like empty string

Answer (score 5):

```
function not_empty_string($s) {
  return $s !== "";
}

array_filter(explode('/', '1/2//3/'), 'not_empty_string');
```

Comment: Note: this is better than the 'bare' call to array_filter() if you might have "1/2//0/3" and want to keep the zero.

Comment: Good comment. I Wanted to suggested the 'bare' call, but yes, it will throw out the zero.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this in [TYPO3](http://doc-typo3.ameos.com/4.1.0/incfile_8php-source.html#l00011), look at the `$onlyNonEmptyValues` parameter:

```
function trimExplode($delim, $string, $onlyNonEmptyValues=0){
    $temp = explode($delim,$string);
    $newtemp=array();
    while(list($key,$val)=each($temp))      {
        if (!$onlyNonEmptyValues || strcmp("",trim($val)))      {
            $newtemp[]=trim($val);
        }
    }
    reset($newtemp);
    return $newtemp;
}
```

It doesn't mess up the indexes:

```
var_dump(trimExplode('/', '1/2//3/',1));
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that should output a newly indexed array.

```
$result = array_deflate( explode( $delim, $array) );

function array_deflate( $arr, $emptyval='' ){
    $ret=[];
    for($i=0,$L=count($arr); $i<$L; ++$i)
        if($arr[$i] !== $emptyval) $ret[]=$arr[$i];
    return $ret;
}
```

While fairly similar to some other suggestion, this implementation has the benefit of generic use. For arrays with non-string elements, provide a typed empty value as the second argument.

`array_deflate( $objArray, new stdClass() );`

`array_deflate( $databaseArray, NULL );`

`array_deflate( $intArray, NULL );`

`array_deflate( $arrayArray, [] );`

`array_deflate( $assocArrayArray, [''=>NULL] );`

`array_deflate( $processedArray, new Exception('processing error') );`

.

.

.

With an optional filter argument..

```
function array_deflate( $arr, $trigger='', $filter=NULL, $compare=NULL){
    $ret=[];
    if ($filter === NULL) $filter = function($el) { return $el; };
    if ($compare === NULL) $compare = function($a,$b) { return $a===$b; };

    for($i=0,$L=count($arr); $i<$L; ++$i)
        if( !$compare(arr[$i],$trigger) ) $ret[]=$arr[$i];
        else $filter($arr[$i]);
    return $ret;
}
```

With usage..

```
function targetHandler($t){ /* .... */ }    
array_deflate( $haystack, $needle, targetHandler );
```

Turning array_deflate into a way of processing choice elements and removing them from your array. Also nicer is to turn the if statement into a comparison function that is also passed as an argument in case you get fancy.

`array_inflate` being the reverse, would take an extra array as the first parameter which matches are pushed to while non-matches are filtered.

```
function array_inflate($dest,$src,$trigger='', $filter=NULL, $compare=NULL){
    if ($filter === NULL) $filter = function($el) { return $el; };
    if ($compare === NULL) $compare = function($a,$b) { return $a===$b; };

    for($i=0,$L=count($src); $i<$L; ++$i)
        if( $compare(src[$i],$trigger) ) $dest[]=$src[$i];
        else $filter($src[$i]);
    return $dest;
}
```

With usage..

```
$smartppl=[];    
$smartppl=array_inflate( $smartppl,
                         $allppl,
                         (object)['intelligence'=>110],
                         cureStupid,
                         isSmart);

function isSmart($a,$threshold){
    if( isset($a->intellgence) )    //has intelligence?
        if( isset($threshold->intellgence) )    //has intelligence?
            if( $a->intelligence >= $threshold->intelligence )
                return true;
            else return INVALID_THRESHOLD; //error
        else return INVALID_TARGET; //error
    return false;
}

function cureStupid($person){
    $dangerous_chemical = selectNeurosteroid();
    applyNeurosteroid($person, $dangerous_chemical);

    if( isSmart($person,(object)['intelligence'=>110]) ) 
        return $person;
    else 
        lobotomize($person);

    return $person;
}
```

Thus providing an ideal algorithm for the world's educational problems. Aaand I'll stop there before I tweak this into something else..

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapper function to strip them

```
function MyExplode($sep, $str)
{
    $arr = explode($sep, $str);
    foreach($arr as $item)
        if(item != "")
            $out[] = $item;
    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to filter the output of the explode function

```
  function filter_empty(&$arrayvar) {
        $newarray = array();
        foreach ($arrayvar as $k => $value)
            if ($value !== "")
                $newarray[$k] = $value;

        $arrayvar = $newarray;
    }
```

Comment: If you're taking in the array as a reference, couldn't you then just unset() the empty-string indexes, without the need for an additional temporary array?

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression solutions tend to be much slower than basic text replacement, so i'd replace double seperators with single seperators, trim the string of any whitespace and then use explode:

```
// assuming $source = '1/2//3/';
$source = str_replace('//', '/', $source);
$source = trim($source);
$parts = explode('/', $source);
```

Comment: But what if it's `1/2////3/`? Your solution only makes one pass and will lease two consecutive slashes.

Answer (score 0):

No regex overhead - should be reasonably efficient, strlen just counts the bytes

Drop the array_values() if you don't care about indexes

Make it into function explode_interesting( $array, $fix_index = 0 ) if you want

```
$interesting = array_values( 
                 array_filter(
                   explode('/', '/1//2//3///4/0/false' ),
                   function ($val) { return strlen($val); }
               ));

echo "<pre>", var_export( $interesting, true ), "</pre>";
```

enjoy, Jeff

Comment: `array_filter()` will happily receive `strlen` as a callback string.

Answer (score -1):

I usually wrap it in a call to [array_filter](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), e.g.

```
var_dump(array_filter(explode('/', '1/2//3/'))
=>
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

Be aware, of course, that array keys are maintained; if you *don't* want this behaviour, remember to add an outer wrapper call to array_values().

Comment: Array filter filtesrs by FALSE by default. You need a callback function to make it work

Comment: Uh, Fire Lancer, read the docs. "Example #2 array_filter() without callback"

Comment: Yeah, it depends what you call "work" - see my comment on James Aylett's post. Ironically, your version will also remove occurrences of "0" in the original string.

Comment: oh ok...I forgot php considered empty strings as FALSe,  though it was just 0 and null

Answer (score -1):

PHP's [split function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) is similar to the explode function, except that it allows you to enter a regex pattern as the delimiter.  Something to the effect of:

```
$exploded_arr = split('/\/+/', '1/2//3/');
```

Comment: This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Comment: Use [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) instead