# Split a comma-delimited string into an array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, csv, explode

I need to split my string input into an array at the commas.

Is there a way to explode a comma-separated string into a flat, indexed array?

Input:

```
9,admin@example.com,8
```

Output:

```
['9', 'admin@example', '8']
```

Comment: Also see [how to split by more than one character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3679042/8740349), like `preg_split('/[-,\s]+/', 'Split-this, by dash comma and space');` for example

Answer (score 721, accepted):

Try [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$myString = "9,admin@example.com,8";
$myArray = explode(',', $myString);
print_r($myArray);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => admin@example.com
    [2] => 8
)
```

Comment: How you can get count ? .lengh?

Comment: One way is to use count() (aka sizeof) - http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Comment: @McLosysCreative You might also like `var_dump` which gives more detailed information. Even more usefull is `var_export($myArray, true)` because it returns the output of `var_dump` as a string so you can store it in some log without breaking generated site...

Answer (score 45):

```
$string = '9,admin@google.com,8';
$array = explode(',', $string);
```

For more complicated situations, you may need to use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split).

Answer (score 32):

If that string comes from a csv file, I would use [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) (or [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) if you have PHP V5.3). That will allow you to parse quoted values correctly. If it is not a csv, [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) should be the best choice.

Answer (score 8):

What if you want your parts to contain commas? Well, quote them. And then what about the quotes? Well, double them up. In other words:

`part1,"part2,with a comma and a quote "" in it",part3`

PHP provides the https://php.net/str_getcsv function to parse a string as if it were a line in a CSV file which can be used with the above line instead of `explode`:

```
print_r(str_getcsv('part1,"part2,with a comma and a quote "" in it",part3'));
Array
(
    [0] => part1
    [1] => part2,with a comma and a quote " in it
    [2] => part3
)
```

Answer (score 5):

`explode` has some very big problems in real life usage:

```
count(explode(',', null)); // 1 !! 
explode(',', null); // [""] not an empty array, but an array with one empty string!
explode(',', ""); // [""]
explode(',', "1,"); // ["1",""] ending commas are also unsupported, kinda like IE8
```

this is why i prefer [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
preg_split('@,@', $string, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

the entire boilerplate:

```
/** @brief wrapper for explode
 * @param string|int|array $val string will explode. '' return []. int return string in array (1 returns ['1']). array return itself. for other types - see $as_is
 * @param bool $as_is false (default): bool/null return []. true: bool/null return itself.
 * @param string $delimiter default ','
 * @return array|mixed
 */
public static function explode($val, $as_is = false, $delimiter = ',')
{
    // using preg_split (instead of explode) because it is the best way to handle ending comma and avoid empty string converted to ['']
    return (is_string($val) || is_int($val)) ?
        preg_split('@' . preg_quote($delimiter, '@') . '@', $val, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
        :
        ($as_is ? $val : (is_array($val) ? $val : []));
}
```

Comment: much prefered this answer, since preg_split is much more foolproof, when it contains user inputs.

Comment: This answer is going to be far less efficient than using `explode()`.  I would not put this in any professional script.  If it is possible for your incoming string to be empty, then write a simple falsey check before exploding instead of using a `preg_` call containing a literal character.  If a string might have a trailing delimiter and you don't want that, then just `rtrim()` the delimiter off -- again, no reason to lean on regex (and I love regex).

Comment: Posted many years earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64608/2943403

Answer (score 4):

Use explode() or preg_split() function to split the string in php with given delimiter

```
// Use preg_split() function 
$string = "123,456,78,000";  
$str_arr = preg_split ("/\,/", $string);  
print_r($str_arr); 
  
// use of explode 
$string = "123,46,78,000"; 
$str_arr = explode (",", $string);  
print_r($str_arr);
```

Comment: A comma does not have special meaning in regex, so there is no need to escape it -- this is only going to teach unnecessary coding practices.  `preg_split()` with a literal character is an inappropriate usage of regex and will only mean needless processing overhead.  I would not recommend the first technique to any researcher.  As for the `explode()` this insight was already offered years earlier.  This answer can be safely deleted.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wants to convert comma seprated string into a list item using for-each then it will help you ...
**This code is for blade template**

```
@php
$data = $post->tags;
$sep_tag= explode(',', $data);
@endphp

@foreach ($sep_tag as $tag)
 <li class="collection-item">{{ $tag}}</li>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be spaces between commas. Also there may be no useful data between commas. Function [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) will help to handle these cases:

```
$str = "1,2 ,  ,4, ";

$arr = preg_split("/\s*,\s*/", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($arr); // [1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//Re-usable function
function stringToArray($stringSeperatedCommas)
{
    return collect(explode(',', $stringSeperatedCommas))->map(function ($string) {
        return trim($string) != null ? trim($string) : null;
    })->filter(function ($string) {
        return trim($string) != null;
    });
}

//Usage
$array = stringToArray('abcd, , dsdsd, dsds');
print($array);

//Result
{ "abcd", "dsdsd", "dsds" }
```

Comment: this works with Laravel >= 5.2

Comment: What is `collect()` supposed to be? You are sharing unusable code. Downvoted.