# How do I split a query value which has commas?

Tags: php, url, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I split a comma delimited string into an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125730/how-can-i-split-a-comma-delimited-string-into-an-array-in-php)

With the example URL format `domain.com/?q[]=a_1&q[]=a_2&q[]=a_3`:

In select option I would retrieve the `selected='selected'` using this code:

```
<option value="a_1"<?php if(isset($_GET['q'])) if (in_array('a_1', $_GET['q'])) { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>
Sample 1
</option>
<option value="a_2"<?php if(isset($_GET['q'])) if (in_array('a_2', $_GET['q'])) { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>
Sample 2
</option>
<option value="a_3"<?php if(isset($_GET['q'])) if (in_array('a_3', $_GET['q'])) { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>
Sample 3
</option>
```

If the URL format were instead  `domain.com/?q=a_1,a_2,a_3`, how would I retrieve the selected value?

Comment: Either make it an array (str_getcsv) first, or search for string parts (strstr) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$vals = explode(',', $_GET['q']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can explode it

```
$arrays = explode(',', $_GET['q']);
```