# PHP function that convert 'a,b' to ' "a","b" '

Tags: php

I have a variable with string value of `'laptop,Bag'` and I want it to look like `' "laptop","Bag" '`or `"laptop","Bag"`. How could I do this one? Is there any php function that could get this job done? Any help please.

Comment: did you even try to do it, it seems pretty much straight forward!

Comment: Yes, I have tried it using implode function but I couldn't make it work

Comment: **Show us what you have tried** and then we can help you fix what you've done wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work. It first, explodes the string into an array. And then implodes it with speech marks & finishes up by adding the opening & closing speech mark.

```
$string = "laptop,bag";
$explode = explode(",", $string);
$implode = '"'.implode('","', $explode).'"';

echo $implode;

Output: 
"laptop","bag"
```

Answer (score 4):

That's what [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/str_replace) is for:

```
$result = '"'.str_replace(',', '","', $str).'"';
```

Comment: Need to add the " at the start & end of string.

Comment: I agree that this would be the more simple method of creating the string. No need to explode or implode anything, and no need to create another function.

Answer (score 2):

This would be very easy to do.

```
$string = 'laptop,bag';
$items = explode(',', $string);
$newString = '"'.implode('","', $items).'"';
```

That should turn `'laptop,bag'` into `"laptop","bag"`.

Wrapping that in a function would be as simple as this:

```
function changeString($string) {
    $items = explode(',', $string);
    $newString = '"'.implode('","', $items).'"';
    return $newString;
}
```

Comment: Beat you to it ;) haha

Comment: Ya, exactly the same thing haha! I provided the function with mine though! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can `explode` your string as array and loop throw it creating your new string

```
function create_string($string)
{
    $string_array = explode(",", $string);
    $new_string = '';
    foreach($string_array as $str)
    {
        $new_string .= '"'.$str.'",';
    }
    $new_string = substr($new_string,-1);

    return $new_string;
 }
```

Now you simply pass your string the function

```
$string = 'laptop,Bag';
echo create_string($string); 
//output "laptop","Bag"
```

Comment: Could use implode isntead of the foreach loop here.

Comment: Correct, my first thought was for looping, implode would be faster though

Answer (score 1):

For your specific example, this code would do the trick:

```
<?php
$string = 'laptop,bag';
$new_string = ' "' . str_replace(',', '","', $string) . '" ';
// $new_string: "laptop","bag"
?>
```

That code would also work if you had more items in that list, as long as they are comma-separated.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`preg_replace()`**](https://www.php.net/preg_replace):

```
$input_lines="laptop,bag";
echo preg_replace("/(\w+)/", '"$1"', $input_lines);
```

**Output:**

```
'"laptop","Bag"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can perform that using explode in php converting that string in to an array.

```
$tags  = "laptop,bag";
$tagsArray = explode(",", $tags);
echo $tagsArray[0]; // laptop
echo $tagsArray[1]; // bag
```

**Reference**
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

related post take a look maybe could solve your problem.

[Split a comma-delimited string into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125730/how-can-i-split-a-comma-delimited-string-into-an-array-in-php)