# How to find a character in a string in PHP?

Tags: php, file

in PHP I am reading a text file with many lines, where each $line have the format: text1,text2,text3,..
so, i am reading with fgets() each line, but i dont know how to assign each variable of the line like $text1 = text1, $text2=text2, etc..
Any help?
thanks in advance

Comment: take a look at the 'explode' function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I split a comma delimited string into an array in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125730/how-can-i-split-a-comma-delimited-string-into-an-array-in-php)

Comment: thanks! explode is working fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `fgetcsv()`. Details [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).  This will pull each line of the file and split the content into an array minus the commas.