# How to split a string into two variables using PHP?

Tags: php

Using PHP how can I split the

```
Szombathely, Hungary
```

into two variables

```
Szombathely
Hungary
```

Thank you!

Comment: And [How can I split a comma delimited string into an array in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1125730) for the more contemporary `str_getcsv` and `preg_split`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )
>   Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$split = explode(',','Szombathely, Hungary');
```

That will, however, leave you with space before `_Hungary`

So if all are `,_` you could use

```
$split = explode(', ','Szombathely, Hungary');
```

or use `trim` on each of array elements.

Answer (score 0):

There is a native command called explode, in which you pass as parameters the delimiter and also the string. More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

In your case it would be:

```
$result = explode ( ',', 'Szombathely, Hungary')
```

as a result you get:

```
$result[0] = 'Szombathely'
$result[1] = 'Hungary'
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "Szombathely, Hungary";
$string = explode(", ", $string);
list($Szombathely, $Hungary) = $string;

var_dump($Szombathely); //Szombathely
var_dump($Hungary);//Hungary`
```