# Split string per int php

Tags: php, regex

```
$string = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8";
$int = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $string), 10);
echo $int; // output will be 12345678
```

I need the output will be like this :

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

Help me pls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I split a comma delimited string into an array in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125730/how-can-i-split-a-comma-delimited-string-into-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..Hope it will works..

The `explode()` function breaks a string into an array.

```
$string = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8";
$arr=explode(',',$string);
foreach ($arr as $a) {
    echo $a."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are over thinking it but if a regex is really needed capture all the integers then implode them.

```
$string = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8";
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+/', $string, $match);
echo implode("\n\n", $match[0]);
```

`Explod`ing then `implod`ing seems like an easier approach though:

```
$string = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8";
echo implode("\n\n", explode(', ', $string));
```

Demo: https://eval.in/697764

Comment: Are you in a web browser?

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to show as your output you can use

```
$string = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8";
$int = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '<br /><br />', $string);
echo $int;
```

another approach (which i would use)

```
$string = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8";
$int = explode(',', $string);
var_dump($int);
```

here all the integer value will be separated and can be use as you like

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php
      $string = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8";

      $int = explode(", ",$string);

      foreach ($int as $value) {
         echo "$value <br>";
        }
 ?>
```

Output

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this example:

```
$string = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8";     
$data= explode(',' ,$string);
echo "<pre>".implode("\n",$data)."</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want PHP output only, then replace the second line of your code with the line below:

```
$int = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', "\n", $string);
```

Note the double quote for the second parameter.

But, if you want output in HTML only, use this:

```
$int = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '<br />', $string);
```

Good luck.