# Comma-separated string to associative array with lowercase keys

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, explode, array-combine

I have a string like this:

```
$string = 'Apple, Orange, Lemone';
```

I want to make this string to:

```
$array = array('apple'=>'Apple', 'orang'=>'Orange', 'lemone'=>'Lemone');
```

How to achieve this?

I used the explode function like this:

```
$string = explode(',', $string );
```

But that only gives me this:

```
Array ( [0] => Apple [1] => Orange [2] => Lemone )
```

Somebody says this question is a duplicate of this SO question: [Split a comma-delimited string into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125730/how-can-i-split-a-comma-delimited-string-into-an-array-in-php)

But that question is not addressing my problem. I have already reached the answer of that question, please read my question. I need to change that result array's key value and case. see:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => admin@example.com
    [2] => 8
)
```

to like this

```
Array
(
    [9] => 9
    [admin@example.com] => admin@example.com
    [8] => 8
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try :

```
$string = 'Apple, Orange, Lemone';
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);

$explode = explode(',',$string);

$res = array_combine($explode,$explode);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
echo '</pre>';
```

Or if you need to make lower case key for resulting array use following :

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_change_key_case($res,CASE_LOWER));
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: You don't need to call explode twice

Comment: this solution gives you array keys in with the same case as the values. The question specifies lowercase array keys.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php 
$string = 'Apple, Orange, Lemone'; // your string having space after each value
$string =str_replace(' ', '', $string); // removing blank spaces
$array = explode(',', $string );
$final_array = array_combine($array, $array);
$final_array = array_change_key_case($final_array, CASE_LOWER); // Converting all the keys to lower case based on your requiment 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($final_array);

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use array functions such as array_combine, and array_values

```
$string = 'Apple, Orange, Lemone';

$arr = explode(', ', $string);

$assocArr = array_change_key_case(
  array_combine(array_values($arr), $arr)
);
```

Comment: that's good. I think the keys really should be run through `trim()` to remove any whitespace.

Comment: seems this the better way of achieving the result, thanx.

Comment: `array_values()` is a useless call here.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$string = 'Apple, Orange, Lemone';
$array = explode(', ', $string);
print_r($array);
```

**output will be**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Apple
    [1] => Orange
    [2] => Lemone
)
```

**Now**

```
$ar = array();
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $ar[$value] = $value;
    }

print_r($ar);
```

**Your Desire Output:**

```
Array
(
    [Apple] => Apple
    [Orange] => Orange
    [Lemone] => Lemone
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$valuesInArrayWithSpace = explode("," $string);

$finalArray = [];

foreach ($ValuesInArrayWitchSpace as $singleItem) {

    $finalArray[trim(strtolower($singleItem))] = trim($singleItem);
}
```

Comment: Why `trim()` the same value twice per iteration?  Why not just split on comma-space?

Answer (score 1):

Or...

```
$csvdata = str_getcsv('Apple,Orange,Lemone');
$arr = [];

foreach($csvdata as $a) {
    $arr[strtolower(trim($a))] = $a;
}

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This way you'll have what you need:

```
$lowerString = strtolower($string);
$values = explode(', ', $string);
$keys   = explode(', ', $lowerString);
$array  = array_combine($keys, $values);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: This approach discards the string case data instead of retaining it in the values.

Answer (score 0):

use array_flip to change the values as key and use array_combine

```
<?php
     $string = 'Apple, Orange, Lemone';
     $array = explode(', ', $string);

     $new_array =array_flip($array);
     $final_array = array_combine($new_array,$array)
     print_r($final_array );

?>
```

Comment: this will give you Array ( [Apple] => 0 [Orange] => 1 [Lemone] => 2 )

Comment: Not only is this snippet missing a semicolon, it does not provide the desired output.  https://3v4l.org/AZ9V4  If this was the desired output, you would only call `explode()` and be done with it.  This answer can be safely removed.

Answer (score 0):

A clean, functional-style approach can use `array_reduce()` after splitting on commas followed by spaces.

Before pushing the new associative values into the result array, change the key to lowercase.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UAlMk))

```
$string = 'Apple, Orange, Lemone';
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        explode(', ', $string),
        fn($result, $v) =>
            $result + [strtolower($v) => $v],
        []
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'apple' => 'Apple',
  'orange' => 'Orange',
  'lemone' => 'Lemone',
)
```