# Format Price in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, format, magento-1.9, price

I am working with Magento 1.9 and it has this code (in php, file `price.phtml`) to echo price in category and product view page:

```
<?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPriceInclTax, true, false) ?>

//echo 199,00€
```

Now I need to display the first number (before comma `199,`) bigger than rest number (`00€`)

Maybe I need a separate class for number before comma and the rest.

Any idea?

Comment: Not sure what the limitations are with Magento, but you could use jQuery to select the last three characters and put them in a span with a separate class, which has a smaller font size

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1125740/7605325 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code

```
<span class='large'><?php echo str_replace(",",",</span><span class='small'>",$_coreHelper->currency($_finalPriceInclTax, true, false)); ?></span>
```

**CSS PART**

```
.large { font-size : 16px; }
.small { font-size : 12px; }
```

Comment: And thnx a lot Bachcha Singh!