# Convert from string to time from database

Tags: php

I have a database linked upto a game. When the game insert's the players "playtime" it adds it like this for each player faction

playtime `"[0,0,0]" (COP,MEDIC,CIV)` - so each of the 0's would represent each player faction.

While the player is playing as that faction only 1 number will update which that number is for that faction.

**Example**
`playtime "[9012,1221,2663]"` - so the player has now played for 
`44 Hours and 23 Minutes` on CIV and `20 Hours and 21 Minutes` on MEDIC and `150 Hours and 12 Minutes` on COP

What I am trying to  is display each number in a table, and show the time in table for each row ...

**EXAMPLE**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>cop</td>
<td>medic</td>
<td>civ</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>150 Hours and 12 Minutes</td>
<td>20 Hours and 21 Minutes</td>
<td>44 Hours and 23 Minutes</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So without displaying it in the time I've posted above, I am wanting to display each output as hour/minutes and in their respective table row.

I currently am using this

`<td> " . str_replace( array('[',']', '"') , ''  ,$row['playtime']). "</td>`

which only shows the time like so **0,0,2891**

If this does not make sense, please tell me.

Comment: Explode the string, then take the parts and convert them into the proper time formats.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but *you need to help yourself first*. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't** working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125730/how-can-i-split-a-comma-delimited-string-into-an-array-in-php

Comment: @MRTM4n, did it when you tried? I'm assuming you've tried.  I won't try it for you. Hence my response about helping yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to create a `DateTime` object, and format your string using [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) created from [`diff()`](https://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php):

```
// $row['playtime'] = '"[9012,1221,2663]"';
// here $row['playtime'] come from your data source

$times = explode(',', trim($row['playtime'], '[]"'));

$times = array_map(function($t) {
        $d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat("U", 0);
        $d2 = DateTime::createFromFormat("U", $t * 60);
        $diff = $d1->diff($d2);
        return ($diff->d * 24 + $diff->h) . " hours, " . $diff->i . " minutes" ;
    }, $times);

print_r($times);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 150 hours, 12 minutes
    [1] => 20 hours, 21 minutes
    [2] => 44 hours, 23 minutes
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have `$row['playtime']` in the form `["nnn,nnn,nnn"]` first **[`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)** away square brakets and double quotes:

```
$playtime = trim( $row['playtime'], '"[]' );
```

Then split the string into an array with the three values with **[`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)**

```
$playtime = explode( ",", $playtime );
```

Use **[`gmdate`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php)** to convert seconds to H:m:s

```
$cop = gmdate( "H:i:s", $playtime[0] );
$med = gmdate( "H:i:s", $playtime[1] );
$civ = gmdate( "H:i:s", $playtime[2] );
```

You'll get each time in the format `hh:mm:ss`

You can go further with

```
$cop = explode( ":", $cop );
$cop = "{$cop[0]} Hours and {$cop[1]} Minutes";
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple but you should show your attempt. 
One way to achieve it would be like below (very vanilla PHP here):

```
$values = "9012,1221,2663";
$minutes = explode(',', $values);
foreach ($minutes as $item) {
    $hours = round(intval($item)/60);
    $minonly = gmp_div_r(intval($item),60);
    echo '<td>' . $hours . ' and ' . $minonly . ' minutes</td>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: My attempt was pretty much the same as the first example

Here
[link](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: So it's not working yet? What's the exact format of your input string? I If it has brackets you can trim it out as suggested in another answer.