# how to get both digits and (.) PHP

Tags: php

i have some ip log i want to return how  you see on example some are random and some others are very long 599999999999999999.599999999999999999.599999999999999999

**Example:**

```
"192.168.0.1" => "192.168"
"1.3.4.5.6.9" => "1.3"
"50005.60005.60001.404" => "50005.60005"
"192.1.2.5" => "192.1"
etc.
```

Comment: could be done with `explode()` and those are not all IP's

Comment: sorry but i have to ask how to use `explode()` i am new student at php

Comment: `$array = explode('.', $yourString);`. That will make an array with each number between the dots. After that you can use `echo $array[0] . '.' . $array[1];` to output the first number, a dot, and the second number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I split a comma delimited string into an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125730/how-can-i-split-a-comma-delimited-string-into-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ip = '192.168.0.1';

$e = explode('.', $ip); // Split on the dot

echo $e[0] . '.' . $e[1]; // Glue back the first 2 pieces
```

`explode()` splits the string into an array using the delimiter (the dot in this case). The array will contain each number (or string) between the delimiter. After that, you can build a new string with that array by concatenating the array keys you need.

Keep in mind that the delimiter will be "lost" after using `explode()`. So you'll have to add that yourself again.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Demo: https://ideone.com/1TxtQy

Comment: You should at the very least explain how your answer works. Just giving "copy / paste" code will solve the issue, but doesn't teach OP anything. He'll be back again later on.

Comment: @icecub i though the text notes and links did that, what would you like (me (or you can)) to add?

Comment: Check my comment to the question. It explains (in short) what's happening. I would add something like that.

Comment: i see it , my others codes were on conflict with **$ip** becuase i use `$ip = array();` now i see how to do it, this did the job thanks

Comment: @game_over_new If an answer helped you out, please click on the checkmark next to it. This will make sure your question doesn't remain open forever and shows your appreciation to the person that helped you out :)