# Get string after '|' character

Tags: php, string

My String is

```
$var = 0|var|var1;
```

i want to save this variable in diffrent variable after | like

```
$var1 = 0;
$var2 = var;
$var3 = var1;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a comma-delimited string into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125730/split-a-comma-delimited-string-into-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the explode() function to split the string and then assign it whatever variable you like (or just use the value in the array):

```
$parts = explode('|', $var); 

$var1 = $parts[0]; 
$var2 = $parts[1]; 
$var3 = $parts[2];
```

Documentation is [here](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 0):

There's also a way to get the values straight into variables, without the array.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

```
list($var1, $var2, $var3) = explode('|', $var);
```

Or since PHP 7.1
https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.symmetric-array-destructuring

```
[$var1, $var2, $var3] = explode('|', $var);
```