# Customize/Trim/Replace Wordpress Single Category Title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to trim the Category Name from left to right. For example the Category Name is **Men | Clothing**, so I want to trim **Men |**, that just **Clothing** is displayed on the page.
I just found a line for trimming at the End:

```
<?php echo rtrim(single_cat_title('', false), 'g'); ?>
```

Or a line for replacing **Men |**, but then the output is **Category: Clothing** :

```
<?php echo str_replace("Men | ", "", get_the_archive_title()); ?>
```

I'm happy about any help. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a comma-delimited string into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125730/split-a-comma-delimited-string-into-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your category name is like this : `$str ="X | Y"` and you want `Y`
You can try this:

`$exp = explode("|", $str)`

`$y = $exp[1]`