# explode on empty string returns array count as 1

Tags: php

`explode` on empty string returns array count as 1.

```
   $consName =explode("|",$docDet['doc_cons_filename']); 
   count($consName);
```

If there is some value in `$docDet['doc_cons_filename']` like `ab|cd|de` then `count($consName)` returns 3.

But its returning 1 if `$docDet['doc_cons_filename']` has empty value.

is it possible to return count as 0 if we perform `count(explode("|",$docDet['doc_cons_filename']))` where `$docDet['doc_cons_filename'] = ""`

Can anyone help me with solution?

Comment: This is becouse the empty string is before the first (and not existing) separator character. Why is this bad for you?

Comment: Yep, `explode()` returns an array. It may only have on element if no delimiter was found.

Comment: That's the expected behavior.

Comment: [Write a wrapper around `explode`](https://gist.github.com/skehlet/a35f0436ba071bd7feca) to give you the behavior you want.

Comment: $myarray=preg_split('/\|/mu', $mystring, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

Comment: $array = ($string == '' ? [] : explode($delimiter, $string))

Comment: use array_filter() like this => count(array_filter($array));

Comment: $cartProducts = strlen($prodID) ? explode(",", $prodID) : array();

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$arr = array();
$str = "yes you are!";
if($i = substr_count($str,"|"))
  $arr = explode("|", $str, $i+1);
echo count($arr);
```

Comment: `explode` returns false if the `delimiter` is blank, not the input string.  Also, you need both parameters in `explode`.

Comment: That is wrong, it only returns `FALSE` when the delimiter string is empty

Comment: you also have your variables mixed up. you save the result of explode to $str then check the count of $arr which is the original variable you are exploding.

Comment: If there is no delimiter in the input string, `count` will still be 0 even the input string is not empty which I don't think is correct. Better answer: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64570/explode-that-doesnt-return-empty-strings?rq=1)

Comment: Topic starter didn't asked about empty delimiter and he didn't asked how to initiate empty array. He asked how to return zero from explode() on empty input string. My example showing you that there is no need to explode string without delimiter at all. Pay attention that If there is no delimiter in string, IF condition from example above will skip the explode line and echo empty array count which is 0. Anyway I agree with you that my example is not perfect, but I don't think that preg_split is a better way to solve this issue.

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to delete this answer, and you will get back the lost reputation.

Comment: It's not about reputation. If topic starter agree that my answer useless, I'll remove my answer.

Comment: `array_filter(explode("|", $string));` did the thing for me! It will filter empty array entries.

Answer (score 10):

The solution would be to count explicitly how many times separator is found within your string. See [`substr_count()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

Comment: There are plenty on the linked page

Comment: use array_filter() like this => count(array_filter($array));The array isn't empty. It has one element which contains a string which is 0 in length.You don't need to pass a second parameter to array_filter() because an empty string will evaluate to false (and hence be removed).