# PHP PDO for NOT IN query in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a post variable called `$_POST['excludeids']` with the following value:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

I want to pass this into an SQL query through `NOT IN` so I use the following query:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM books WHERE id NOT IN (:excludeids)");
$STH->bindValue(':excludeids', $_POST['excludeids']);
$STH->execute();
```

Binding the variable doesn't work in this context I don't know why. What's wrong with the above query?

Comment: Missing a `"` in the SQL statement

Comment: corrected this mistake  :)

Comment: see this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't work in this way because an `IN()` clause expects a collection of values, not a comma separated string, which is what you are providing by attempting to bind them all as a single argument.

In order to make this work you will need to bind each element in the collection individually:

```
// Split the IDs into an array
$ids = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $_POST['excludeids'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

// Create an array of ? characters the same length as the number of IDs and join
// it together with commas, so it can be used in the query string
$placeHolders = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));

// Prepare the statement
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM books WHERE id NOT IN ($placeHolders)");

// Iterate the IDs and bind them
// Remember ? placeholders are 1-indexed!
foreach ($ids as $index => $value) {
    $STH->bindValue($index + 1, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}

// This should now work
$STH->execute();
```

Comment: Now I'm facing another problem...I want to bind another variable using `$STH->bindValue(':test', $_POST['test']);` but I'm getting the following error: `Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters`

Comment: @MichaelSamuel You will need to use question mark-style placeholders throughout the query in order for the above code to work - but you can easily at more at the appropriate place. If your extra param needs to go before the `IN()` clause, simply `bindValue(1, 'Your value')` before the loop and change `$index + 1` to `$index + 2`.

Comment: Ok solved that but having another problem...why do i have to do the preg_split? When I tried to replace the first line in your code with `$ids = array($_POST['excldeids'])` the query returns nothing...I tried to send the string in jquery as `'1','2','3'` instead of `1,2,3` but still it returns nothing

Comment: Because `$_POST['excldeids']` is a comma separated string. You need it to be an array, with each comma-separated value as an element. `array($_POST['excldeids'])` would simply create an array with one element, your original comma-separated string.

Comment: If I push the ids as an array using javascript...is there a way to use it directly in PHP instead of having to preg_split?

Comment: @MichaelSamuel If you are using jQuery, it provides a helper function called [`jQuery.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) which will create a correctly formatted string for you to use directly in PHP. Alternatively you could use `JSON.stringify()` to pass the parameter as JSON, and then `json_decode()` it in PHP. But at the end of the day, the data is always being passed into a PHP as a string ans you will always need to decode it to an array - all the mechanisms are very similar.

Comment: I found that using PHP explode function is faster and easier than the preg_split...thanks Dave very much for your effort :)

Comment: @MichaelSamuel As long your input string contains nothing but commas and digits, `explode()` will work fine. The only reason I went with `preg_split()` was to account for unwanted white space.

Comment: [Explanation for using `preg_split` instead of `explode`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/64608/318765)

Answer (score 3):

You will have to loop thru the ids (first exploding them into an array) and create new parameters dynamically, both in the SQL string and with `bindValue`.

Comment: They are string, not array, I think

Comment: i pass this as a string using jquery

Comment: can you show me an example because I can't understand you..thanks :)

Comment: i posted a question for your reference. look above

Comment: Now I'm facing another problem...I want to bind another variable using `$STH->bindValue(':test', $_POST['test']);` but I'm getting the following error: `Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $all_id = array(1, 2, 3, 4,5);
    $countArr = count($all_id);
    for($countArr; $countArr > 0; $countArr--)
        $in[]= '?';
    $in = implode(', ', $in);   
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
        SELECT ID
        FROM  b_iblock_element 
        WHERE  XML_ID NOT IN  ( ".$in.")
    ");
    if ($stmt->execute($all_id)) {
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<pre>'; print_r($row); echo'</pre>';
        }
    }
    $stmt->execute();
```