# php, csv Parse string from csv file

Tags: php, csv

I have this string:

```
$myString = "toto;titi;tata;;;;tutu;;tyty";
```

I wish with : explode(';', $myString);

```
["toto","titi","tata","","","","tutu","","tyty"]
```

but i have :

```
$result = ["toto","titi","tata","tutu","tyty"];
```

I lose the values ​​empty chains, I want to keep them.

I do not know how to do it, someone would have a solution plz ?

Comment: Have you tried: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: Use [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/fgetcsv]) function please.

Comment: what do I do incorrect ? - https://eval.in/781080

Comment: @splash58: Good point, it gives the same result as `str_getcsv()`. Nevertheless, you should use `str_getcsv()` when it is a line from a CSV file.

Comment: Already answered [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64570/explode-that-doesnt-return-empty-strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64570/explode-that-doesnt-return-empty-strings) I didn't tried the solution.